# Twitter.com in private browsing leaks data to normal browser. Other sites as well? Bug or feature?

Tags: web-browser, privacy, data-leakage, browser-extensions, twitter

This is the first time I encountered similar thing. When I log into the Twitter web site in Chrome (namely, the Iron version which is said to be [security enhanced](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron_chrome_vs_iron.php), but that does not matter here) in private browsing mode it automatically logs me into my Twitter account in the main browser window as well.

- Is it a feature of Twitter?
- Or a bug of Chrome?

This can be very embarrassing, indeed.

Other web sites or other browsers are more secure regarding this issue? Is it possible that one of my add-ons leak? I only have Alexa and HTTP Everywhere. This would be very dangerous.

In 2010 August the following news circulated through the tech media: [Private browsing modes leak data](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-10891355)

Edit: I just replicated the same error on a freshly installed Google Chrome on a freshly installed Windows 7. The culprit is the HTTPS Everywhere add-on.

Comment: Can't replicate this in my chrome install (normal v28)

Comment: I don't see the issue. Isn't private browsing mode designed to prevent additive behaviour, rather than act as a blank slate? Your previous non-private session cookies will still be accessible in private mode, but new ones will not be stored beyond the private session.

Comment: AFAIK Iron isn't really any better than pure Chromium. It simply changes the default value of some settings.

Comment: I see you have answered your own question. Please add and mark it as an aswer. Do note that you use a non-standard Chrome/Chromium

Answer (score 6):

This is not a feature in Twitter or the Chrome version you're using. It's either a bug in the browser or a misconfiguration on your side.

Please refrain from using non-standard and non-official browsers. Instead of using SRWare Iron (a fork of Chromium), you should use Chrome, which can be easily configured to reach your privacy goals.

Comment: What makes a browser "official"? (I think the word you want is *reputable*.)